# Node 5.6 Doesn't Understand ES6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

Trying both `node` and `node --harmony` but I continue to get the 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token import' error.

I have two files, `A.ts` and `B.ts`. Here is what they look like-

**B.ts**

```
export class B {

}
```

**A.ts**

```
import {B} from './B';

console.log(new B());
```

Which results in-

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {B} from './B';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:140:18)
    at node.js:1001:3
```

Why?

Comment: Your problem is with TypeScript, not Node, I think.

Comment: Is the above not plain-jane es6?

Comment: It's ES6. Nothing TypeScript here at all.

Comment: Harmony modules are still in progress. You can reference the docs here: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/ or as mentioned, grep for anything in progress.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh it was a guess from the `.ts` extension on the files. A bad guess, I guess :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules are still in progress, I'm not sure if trying to throw the flag will fix your error but here's the command:

```
$ node --v8-options | grep 'in progress'
--harmony_modules (enable "harmony modules" (in progress))
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time away from your music to answer my question. Didn't work. What are you using? A transpiler?

Comment: @MicahWilliamson You're quite welcome, not sure what you're asking exactly. Am I using a transpiler for what? Are you trying to compile TypeScript (assuming because of your .ts extensions)?

Comment: I was trying to run node again the src files instead of the build files (just trying to avoid additional complication if possible). I can run against an ES5 build for now.

Comment: I do remember now actually. If I build to ES5 I have to include a promise library. I was trying to use native ES6 promises.

Answer (score -1):

Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node. It allows compiling of typescript a la node.

Also make sure your tsconfig.json is set to compile with commonjs. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json

Here is what my tsconfig.json looks like:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": false
  }
}
```